# JQuery tablesorter plugin is not showing table data in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using JQuery 1.9.0, TableSorter 2.0 in my javascript application.

My data table doesnt seem to render on the screen. I checked that the data is available in the object but that shows only heading but data is not visible.

```
$("#tblErrorMessages").html(errorTable);
$("#tblErrorMessages").
   tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, positionFixed: false }).
   tablesorterPager({ container: $("#errorpager"), positionFixed: false });

$("#errordiv").css('position', 'relative');
$("#errorpager").css('position', 'relative');
```

This is how the table is visible on the screen.

[image: ScreenShot]

Is there a specific dependency for IE 11 ? I cannot upgrade to newer versions of JQuery or tablesorter as there are other depending libraries which cant be modified now. 
Any work around for this?

Comment: Please share more of your code. Is tablesorter already initialized when the above code is called? If so, trigger an "update" instead of calling the plugin. What version of tablesorter is being used? Any errors in the console?

Comment: My data loads after some server calls. So this is where the tablesorter is initialized. My tablesorter version is 2.0 ( as mentioned in the question)

Comment: There is no tablesorter v2.0... do you mean v2.0.5 ([original](http://tablesorter.com/docs/))? Or v2.30.5 ([forked version](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)). Tablesorter should only be initialized once... when new data is loaded, an "update" event should be triggered on the table.